# Dynamically access oneof value from a protobuf

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

Let's say I defined a protobuf message like this

```
message Config {
    oneof config{
         A a = 1;
         B b = 2;
    }
}
```

now inside python code, when I am parsing a message instance of Config, I can get the one of field name with

```
field = config.WhichOneof('config')
```

but how should I access A with the fieldname I got? I don't want to write something like:

```
if field == 'a':
    return config.a
else
    return config.b
```

because I just want to get the underline value with either a or b, I already know its type. Is there a better solution? thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use `getattr`:

```
data = getattr(config, config.WhichOneof('config')).value
```

Since `WhichOneof('config')` returns either `'a'` or `'b'`, just use `getattr` to access the attribute dynamically.